# Отправить координаты картинки посредством ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, javascript

JS

```
$( function () {
  $( '.cropimage' ).each( function () {
    var image = $(this),
        cropwidth = image.attr('cropwidth'),
        cropheight = image.attr('cropheight'),
        results = image.next('.results' ),
       x       = $('.cropX', results),
        x       = $('.cropX', results),
        y       = $('.cropY', results),
        w       = $('.cropW', results),
        h       = $('.cropH', results),
        download = results.next('.download').find('a');
      image.cropbox( {width: cropwidth, height: cropheight, showControls: 'auto' } )
        .on('cropbox', function( event, results, img ) {
          x.text( results.cropX );
          y.text( results.cropY );
          w.text( results.cropW );
          h.text( results.cropH );

        });
  } );
} );
```

HTML

```
<img class="cropimage" cropwidth="400" cropheight="200" src="1.JPG">
  <div class="results">
    <b>X</b>: <span class="cropX"></span>
    <b>Y</b>: <span class="cropY"></span>
    <b>W</b>: <span class="cropW"></span>
    <b>H</b>: <span class="cropH"></span>
  </div>
```

[Ссылка на плагин](http://acornejo.github.io/jquery-cropbox/)

Как отправить координаты картинки посредством ajax?

Comment: по клике допустим на Save достать значения с X Y W H и отправить!

Comment: В этом и вопрос - Как мне их достать? В браузер все выводится, а как их извлечь для обработки не пойму. 
Подвопрос - А вообще, возможно ли отправить координаты (ajax-ом), при
отпускании левой клавиши мыши?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Я немного модифицировал код из вашего примера. Работающий пример тут [link text](http://jsfiddle.net/pvkovalev/53fE9/)

Итак CSS

```
body {
    font-family : sans-serif;
    font-size : 13px;
}
.results {
    font-family : monospace;
    font-size : 20px;
}
```

HTML

```
<img class="cropimage" alt="" src="http://acornejo.github.io/jquery-cropbox/img.jpg" cropwidth="200" cropheight="200" />
<div class="results"> <b>X</b>: <span class="cropX"></span>
 <b>Y</b>: <span class="cropY"></span>
 <b>W</b>: <span class="cropW"></span>
 <b>H</b>: <span class="cropH"></span>

</div>
<div class="download"> <a href="#" download="crop.png">Download</a>

</div>
<br/>

 <h4>Change size of every cropbox</h4>

<select id="select">
    <option value="200" selected>200</option>
    <option value="300">300</option>
</select>
<div id="output"></div>
```

И наконец JavaScript

```
    $(function () {
    $('.cropimage').each(function () {
        var image = $(this),
            cropwidth = image.attr('cropwidth'),
            cropheight = image.attr('cropheight'),
            results = image.next('.results'),
            x = $('.cropX', results),
            y = $('.cropY', results),
            w = $('.cropW', results),
            h = $('.cropH', results),
            download = results.next('.download').find('a');

        image.cropbox({
            width: cropwidth,
            height: cropheight,
            showControls: 'auto'
        }).on('cropbox', function (event, results, img) {
            x.text(results.cropX);
            y.text(results.cropY);
            w.text(results.cropW);
            h.text(results.cropH);
            //download.attr('href', img.getDataURL());
        });
    });
});

$(document).on('change', '#select', function () {
    //$('#select').on('change', function () {
    var size = parseInt(this.value);
    $('.cropimage').each(function () {
        $(this).cropbox({
            width: size,
            height: size
        })
    });
});

//здесь мы сохраняем данные
$(document).on('cropbox', '.cropimage', function (event, results, img) {
    var date = Date();
    var html = date + ' X ' + results.cropX + ' Y ' + results.cropY + ' W ' + results.cropW + ' H ' + results.cropH + '<br/>';
    $('#output').html(html);
    $('#output').attr('temp',html);
});

//а тут делаем вызов ajax вместо alert
$(document).on('mouseup', '.cropimage', function () {
    var data = $('#output').attr('temp');
    alert(data);
});
```

Надеюсь я ответил на ваш вопрос :-)

Comment: Да - все вопросы закрыты полностью) - спасибо